# External camera tracking metaio

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, metaio

I have one question here..

I've been using unity and metaio sdk to make a desktop application, it is a simple AR apps and im using an external camera to track the marker. My problem is, when im using an external camera, the AR did not work, meaning there is no 3D model being superimposed at the marker although the external camera sees the marker..But when i switch back to internal camera, it works wonderfully..

So is there anything that i can do to fix this? Im new to metaio..

Thanks..

Comment: You mean unity as in unity3d or as the .net library?

Comment: Hello steven.. I mean as in unity3d..do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You might want to post to Game Development Stack Exchange. They might be able to help you more.

Comment: Hello Bitcoin..thank you for your reply..i will post there